# Check radio button for null value in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a property of type `int?` which can have the values 1, 2, 3 or null.

I want to render 4 radio buttons to represent those choices. For the value 1, 2 and 3 something like this works great:

```
<input type="radio" asp-for="Score" value="3" class="form-control" />
```

However, if I do something like this for the null value it only partially works:

```
<input type="radio" asp-for="Score" value="" class="form-control" />
```

When I submit the form, model binding puts null into the property value as expected, but when the form is rendered if `Score` is null then **none** of the radio buttons are checked.

I know I can use some "null substitute value" like 0, but before I start writing lots of `if (x == 0) x = null;` code in my controllers I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your second line of codes to

```
<input type="radio" asp-for="Score" value="" class="form-control" 
    @(Model.Score == null ? "checked='checked'" : "")/>
```

In this way, this radio will be checked if `Model.Score == null` when the form is rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer 胡玮文, but I already tried this. Something strange is happening which means attributes are not just text when working with tag helpers. If fact, the output of the razor code and any attributes following it don't get output into the HTML.